# Can't update table using jQuery after ajax request

Tags: jquery, html-table

I get a table from the server using ajax request. After I insert the table to the html I want to make some modifications but it doesn't work.

My code is simple:

```
$.get("someurl", function(data) {
    $("#scenarios").html(data)
}); 
$("#scenarios table tr:first").append("<th>bla</th>"); 
$("#scenarios table tr:gt(0)").append("<td><input type='checkbox'></td>");
```

I see the table, but I the last two lines doesn't work.
If I copy those two lines and insert them in Chrome console (F12) it works perfectly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

due to the async nature of `ajax`, the selectors you have written execute before the table is added, move these line inside the success call back

```
$.get("someurl", function(data) {
    $("#scenarios").html(data);
    $("#scenarios table tr:first").append("<th>bla</th>"); 
    $("#scenarios table tr:gt(0)").append("<td><input type='checkbox'></td>");
});
```

Comment: thanks, it work now.
just curios - how can I make the request synchronous ?

Comment: set `async:false` to make it synchronous

Answer (score 2):

Because `get` is asynchronous, the two lines immediately after it will execute before the request has returned its response. You would need to move those lines inside the callback function:

```
$.get("someurl", function(data) {
    $("#scenarios").html(data);
    $("#scenarios table tr:first").append("<th>bla</th>"); 
    $("#scenarios table tr:gt(0)").append("<td><input type='checkbox'></td>");
});
```

Also note that you're missing a semi-colon on the first line of the callback function. It's not vital, but it's good practice to use semi-colons wherever they should appear.